# Access the root in Ubuntu bash on Windows 10

Tags: windows, bash, root

I'm trying to use a program called Packmol using an Ubuntu Bash on Windows 10, but for this program to work I need to move the "packmol" file into the "bin" folder in the Bash's root (I don't know why but that's what I was told to do). Which is located in this directory:

"C:\Users\paulo\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\bin"

The folder exists and I can access it in Windows, I can even move files, but when I move them using Windows Explorer the program does not work so I think I need to do this using the Bash. I already did this on macOS and Ubuntu and it worked.

But when I try to access the "rootfs" folder by Bash it gives me "Permission Denied" and when I try to use "sudo cd rootfs" it says "No such file or directory".

Can someone help me?

Sorry for my ignorance with Ubuntu/linux and my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rootfs in the Windows file path refers to / in the Linux subsystem. I think you're supposed to move the packmol file to /bin, so you should do "sudo mv packmol /bin/".

As for the reason why, moving the packmol executable file to /bin/ allows you to directly call the program in the shell without typing the full file path to the program.